# Setting up kafka flink connector project with example

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink

As i am new to kafka flink connector help me in suggesting some simple example program where kafka writes in a topic and flink listens it and display the values along with pom.xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Flink operations playground does exactly that. This is a complete environment for learning about how to use Flink. [The documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/getting-started/docker-playgrounds/flink-operations-playground.html) describes what this application is doing, how to start and stop it, how to use the Flink Web UI, REST API, and CLI to control and observe what's happening, etc.

This docker-based example includes:

- a Kafka broker plus Zookeeper
- [a simple click event generator that writes events to a Kafka input topic](https://github.com/apache/flink-playgrounds/blob/master/docker/ops-playground-image/java/flink-playground-clickcountjob/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/playgrounds/ops/clickcount/ClickEventGenerator.java)
- [a Flink application that counts these events with time windows and writes the results to Kafka output topic](https://github.com/apache/flink-playgrounds/blob/master/docker/ops-playground-image/java/flink-playground-clickcountjob/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/playgrounds/ops/clickcount/ClickEventCount.java)
- a small Flink cluster to run the Flink job

The pom.xml file is [here](https://github.com/apache/flink-playgrounds/blob/master/docker/ops-playground-image/java/flink-playground-clickcountjob/pom.xml).

Comment: can you explain about what the above program does?

Comment: Every 15 seconds the event generator is writing 1000 click events for each of 6 pages to a Kafka input topic. The Flink job reads and counts those events and writes the results to a Kafka output topic.